# "Missing ) after condition."

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a beginner at writing codes, actually it's my first code. My problem is this message "Missing ) after condition.". I tried everything but nothing worked, please someone helps me!

```
var calendar = sheet.getRange("B4:H9");
  var arr1 = [calendar.getCell(r = 0, c = 0).getValue];

  var interval = sheet.getRange("B13:B");
  var arr2 = [interval.getCell(rr = 0, 0).getValue];

  for(r; r < arr1.length; r++)
  {
    for(c; c < arr1.leangth[r]; c++)
    {
      for(rr; rr < dia.leangth[0]; rr++)
      {
        if(calendar.getCell(r,c).getValue() === interval.getCell(rr,0)getValue()) //<---Here is the Problem
        {
          arr1.getCell(r,c).setBackground('Blue');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `getCell(rr,0)getValue()` I think you're missing something here ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you didn't add the `.` before calling the `.getValue()` function.

So you should update your line of code to this:

```
if(calendar.getCell(r,c).getValue() === interval.getCell(rr,0).getValue())
```

Furthermore, here are some links that might be of help to you:

1. [Apps Script Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials);
2. [Apps Script Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview);
3. [Class Range - getValue() function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue).